# Incorrect Syntax in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, syntax

I have written a stored procedure and am getting incorrect syntax near line 64 commit

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Transactions_Create
(@AccountID INT, @EmplNo smallint,@Amount Money,@Description     VARCHAR(100),@EnteredBy VARCHAR(41),@Type char(1),
  @TransId INT OUTPUT)

AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN Transaction
        Declare @ActType dbo.AccountType
        select @ActType =Type from dbo.Accounts
        where AccountId=@AccountID;

Declare @Withdraw smallint
select @Withdraw
=WithdrawalCount from dbo.Accounts
where AccountId=@AccountId

Declare @ServiceFee Money
Declare @withdrawchange smallInt
Declare @balancechange Money

if @Type='D'
    BEGIN 
        SET @ServiceFee=0.0;
        SET @withdrawchange=0;
        SET @balancechange=@Amount;

    end;
else 
    BEGIN       
        SET @withdrawchange=1;
        if @ActType='cheaquing' 
            begin
                SET @ServiceFee=0.50;
            end
            else
                begin
                    if @Withdraw<2
                        begin 
                            SET @ServiceFee=0.0;
                    end
                    else
                        begin
                            SET @ServiceFee=1.00;
                        end
    SET @balancechange=(@Amount-@ServiceFee)*-1;
    end
update dbo.Accounts 
SET Balance= balance+@balancechange, WithdrawalCount=WithdrawalCount+@withdrawchange
where AccountId=@AccountId;

INSERT Into dbo.Transactions(AccountID, EmplNo ,Amount, Description    ,EnteredBy ,Type)

values (@AccountID, @EmplNo ,@Amount, @Description ,@EnteredBy ,@Type );

SET @TransID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

commit Transaction;
```

I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax. Everything looks correct to me, From what I understood everything should go inside the BEGIN TRANSACTION COMMIT TRANSACTION block so I do not understand why this is failing

Comment: I'm guessing your `end`s don't line up with the `begin`s.

Comment: Read the error message. Think about the error message and break down "the problem" into smaller parts until the actual problem area is identified. Fix the problem and build the code/syntax/query back up, making sure not to break it again. If there is still a problem (after identifying some relevant code) then ask .. *and include the relevant errors*.

Answer (score 0):

Declare all of your variables prior to the AS statement and begin transaction. that should help this out

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Transactions_Create

@AccountID INT, 
@EmplNo smallint,
@Amount Money,
@Description VARCHAR(100),
@EnteredBy VARCHAR(41),
@Type char(1),
@TransId INT OUTPUT,
@Withdraw smallint,
@ServiceFee Money,
@withdrawchange smallInt,
@balancechange Money,
@ActType dbo.AccountType

AS
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN Transaction
        select @ActType =Type from dbo.Accounts
        where AccountId=@AccountID;


select @Withdraw = WithdrawalCount from dbo.Accounts
where AccountId=@AccountId

if @Type='D'
    BEGIN 
        SET @ServiceFee=0.0;
        SET @withdrawchange=0;
        SET @balancechange=@Amount;

    end;
else 
    BEGIN       
        SET @withdrawchange=1;
        if @ActType='cheaquing' 
            begin
                SET @ServiceFee=0.50;
            end
            else
                begin
                    if @Withdraw<2
                        begin 
                            SET @ServiceFee=0.0;
                    end
                    else
                        begin
                            SET @ServiceFee=1.00;
                        end
     SET @balancechange=(@Amount-@ServiceFee)*-1;
    end
update dbo.Accounts 
SET Balance= balance+@balancechange, WithdrawalCount=WithdrawalCount+@withdrawchange
where AccountId=@AccountId;

INSERT Into dbo.Transactions(AccountID, EmplNo ,Amount, Description ,EnteredBy ,Type)

values (@AccountID, @EmplNo ,@Amount, @Description ,@EnteredBy ,@Type );

SET @TransID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

commit Transaction;
```

Comment: Tried to move the declares as you suggested still giving the same syntax error

Comment: try replacing the SET XACT_ABORT ON with BEGIN TRY right under the BEGIN TRANSACTION, and the put END TRY, BEGIN CATCH, ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; END CATCH; after the COMMIT TRANSACTION.

Comment: Shouldn't this line: select @Withdraw = WithdrawalCount from dbo.Accounts
where AccountId=@AccountId
have  ; at the end also?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks like it was just a missing end